# Creating a new window with Stetic GUI Designer raises an error on Build() method

Tags: c#, xamarin, monodevelop, gtk#

I'm testing monodevelop with xamarin-studio using C# , gtk# and Stetic GUI Designer.

My problem is when I create a new window (Fenêtre = Window):

[image]

I got the following error in my generated cs class :

[image]

Am I doing something wrong ? Because I just use the Xamarin interface in order to create the Window and I do not do anything more.

Moreover, when I add a widget in my new window (called TestWindow) I can't retrieve this widget in my TestWindow.cs class as if it doesn't exists.

Do you have any ideas to help me ? (Looking for this issue on google didn't help me)

NB : I'm working on MacOS system, and didn't try it on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding a new GTK# window you need to compile your project so the code for the Build method is generated.